# css page break in ie8 (iframe)

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, page-break

I have a page where I put 3 iframes that show other 3 pages in them.
Everything is wrapped in a big DIV element and every iframe is wrapped in its own DIV element.
Between each DIV, I put another DIV element with the following CSS code:

```
@media print { .page-break {display:block; page-break-before:always;} }
```

In Firefox (version 12 in this case, but I guess it's not a version issue), everything is as it's supposed to be in printing the entire page, but in IE8 it seems like the page break CSS isn't working at all and the pages get messed up in printing.

I came across an answer here that this page break does not work on positioned elements, but in my case the elements with this CSS code are the DIVs in between as I describe here AND the positioning of the content of the printed pages (relative/absolute, float) is done only in the source of the pages, contained within the iframes and not in the main page, so I'm not sure that this is the reason for the situation I'm encountering here.

What do I have to do in order to get this page break to work correctly on IE8 too?

This is the code of the MAIN page:

```
<style>
@media print { .page-break {display:block; page-break-before:always;} }
</style>

<div align="left">
<div id="frame_gop" align="left" style="width:759px;height:980px;">
<iframe src="page1.html" width="759" height="980" frameborder="0" align="left"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="page_break"></div>
<div id="frame_report" align="left" style="width:759px;height:980px;">
<iframe src="page2.html" width="759" height="980" frameborder="0" align="left"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="page_break"></div>
<div id="frame_release" align="left" style="width:759px;height:980px;">
<iframe src="page3.html" width="759" height="980" frameborder="0" align="left"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can start by using process of elimination. Set a background-color to each div and remove the iframe elements within. Do you still experience the issue? If so, it is probably NOT because of the iframes, so focus on your divs. Now, this is kind of a guess, but try explicitly setting your divs to position: relative.

Answer (score 1):

@media queries not supported in IE8, remove it. just use simple classes

**Replace:**

```
@media print { .page-break {display:block; page-break-before:always;} }
```

**From:**

```
.page-break {display:block; page-break-before:always;}
```

Thanks